# Get print from printer using android via USB OTG

Tags: android

Anyone have idea or links or code for connecting and printing through usb OTG cable connected to the printer using android.

Thanks,
Nandakishore.

Comment: On API Level 19+, it is possible that this will be supported through Android's [printing framework](http://developer.android.com/training/printing/index.html), though I doubt it.

Comment: thanks commonsWare for the link, but is it something for USB print?

Comment: It is the only thing related to printing in Android itself. Either it works for you or it does not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution,

```
PrintManager printManager = (PrintManager)this.getSystemService(Context.PRINT_SERVICE);
String jobName = this.getString(R.string.app_name) + " Report";
    PrintPDFAdapter pda = new PrintPDFAdapter(pdfFile, filename);
    PrintAttributes attrib = new PrintAttributes.Builder().
            setMediaSize(PrintAttributes.MediaSize.NA_LETTER.asLandscape()).
            setMinMargins(PrintAttributes.Margins.NO_MARGINS).
            build();
    printManager.print(jobName, pda, attrib);
```

But corresponding printer driver app has to be installed before going to use above code.